# Error running WSGI application ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'f_worldSHop' File "/var/www/fworld_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py"

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have facing issues when i deploy a django project on pythonanywhere error below

```
Error running WSGI application  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
No module named 'f_worldSHop' File "/var/www/fworld_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py"
```

wsgi.py

```
path = '/home/Fworld/f-worldshop/f_worldSHop'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'f_worldSHop.settings'

## then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Inner project Path

```
README.txt  f-worldshop
(myenv) 21:33 ~ $ cd f-worldshop/
(myenv) 21:33 ~/f-worldshop (master)$ ls
db.sqlite3  f_Usershop  f_shop  f_worldSHop  manage.py  media  requirements.txt
(myenv) 21:33 ~/f-worldshop (master)$ pwd
/home/Fworld/f-worldshop
(myenv) 21:34 ~/f-worldshop (master)$ cd f_worldSHop/
(myenv) 21:34 ~/f-worldshop/f_worldSHop (master)$ pwd
/home/Fworld/f-worldshop/f_worldSHop
```

> Error running WSGI application  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> No module named 'f_worldSHop' File "/var/www/fworld_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py"
> Error running WSGI application  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> No module named 'f_worldSHop' File "/var/www/fworld_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py"

Answer (score 0):

With this setup you should rather have `path` set to `/home/Fworld/f-worldshop/` in the wsgi file.